# jquery selected value in drop down

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a drop down. How do I get the selected option, not the value but `innerHTML`. I want `CO` from the example. This `alert($('#mydropdown').val());` gives me the value `1` but I dont want that.

```
<select name='mydropdown' id='dd'>
<option value=1 selected>CO</option>
<option value=2>CA</option>

<option value=3>TX</option>

</select>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('#dd :selected').text();
```

Note that using `#`, you're selecting by ID. The ID of your element is `dd`, not `mydropdown`.

If you were to do it with plain javascript, you would want to have your `name` attribute match the `id` attribute in order to deal with IE bugs.

```
<select name='dd' id='dd'>
   ...
</select>
```

js

```
var select = document.getElementById('dd')
select.options[select.selectedIndex].text;
```

Comment: Great answer, especially for the pure JS part. Even better, HTML5 will  give us `select.selectedOptions[0]` -- we can dream, can't we?!

Comment: @lonesomeday - Indeed we can. :o) Thanks for the HTML5 note.

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#dd").val();
```

That's all you need to do.

Comment: John, OP wanted the text content, not the value attribute. This would work to get the text, only if the `options` don't have a value.